# PyEphem (sunrise / sunset time calculation) equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, python, astronomy

[PyEphem](http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) is a neat library that allows easy calculation of sunrise, set, dawn, and dusk of location based on lat, long, and UTC timestamp

I don't want to go through the [calculation](http://www.srrb.noaa.gov/highlights/sunrise/calcdetails.html) myself, rather I was wondering if there is an existing library I could use

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SunTime.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/SolarCalculator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but check out [CoordinateSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoordinateSharp/). It can do exactly what you described. It can even do Solar/Lunar eclipse calculations.

Example Usage:

```
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(19.0991676, -98.2209974, DateTime.Now());
c.CelestialInfo.SunRise; //Returns sunrise nullable DateTime for location.
```